# How to redirect to a specific view controller using today extension?

Tags: ios, swift

I can't redirect to a specific view controller when clicking on a button of today extension widget.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let urlHost : String = url.host as String!
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "BLE", bundle: nil)

    if(urlHost == "BLELoginViewController")
    {

        let innerPage: BLELoginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BLELoginViewController") as! BLELoginViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = innerPage
    }

    return true
}


class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    }

    func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

        // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
        // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
        // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData


        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
    }

    @IBAction func extensionAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "UEM://BLELoginViewController")!

        self.extensionContext?.open(url as URL, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "I can't redirect"? Does your app crash? Does it fail to compile? Does it fail to do anything?

Comment: crash when open the widget

Comment: There's a thousand reasons your app could crash. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example with your question.

Comment: is there any recommended tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that UEM is installed in your device.And have a try follow code:

```
let urlString = "UEM://BLELoginViewController"
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                self.extensionContext?.open(url, options: [:],
                                          completionHandler: {
                                            (success) in
                })
            } else {
                self.extensionContext?.open(url)
            }
        }
```

And Comment out the code first to test whether can open it not with special view:

```
//let urlHost : String = url.host as String!
//let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "BLE", bundle: nil)
//if(urlHost == "BLELoginViewController")
//{
//    let innerPage: BLELoginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BLELoginViewController") as! BLELoginViewController
//self.window?.rootViewController = innerPage
//}
```

Comment: Got error shown: 'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

Comment: Sorry, swift 3.0 need to use `self.extensionContext?.open`,i will check other possible reason.